# Xamarin Android: Get ALL processes located in memory

Tags: c#, process, xamarin.android

Is there a way to read out all processes, not only the running processes.

If I understood Android correctly, only one process is running at a time, and every other process is frozen (background processes ignored)

Answer (score 1):

You can get all of androids currently running app processes by using the following code snippet:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)BaseContext.GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);
ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
activityManager.GetMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);

List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcesses = activityManager.RunningAppProcesses as List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo>;
```

You can then loop through the list called `runningAppProcesses` and interrogate the process information class for other bits of information if required, these can be [found listed here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.activitymanager.runningappprocessinfo)

Here's a couple of examples:

- **ProcessName**   - The name of the process that this object is associated with.
- **Pid**   - The pid of this process; 0 if none.
- **Uid**   - The user id of this process.

**EDIT:**

As per the ops comment below, that they need 'frozen' (suspended) processes, here's some additional information:

It used to be that you could grab a list of running tasks, not quite the same as processes but are defined by android as:

> Return a list of the tasks that are currently running, with the most
>   recent being first and older ones after in order. Note that "running"
>   does not mean any of the task's code is currently loaded or activity
>   -- the task may have been frozen by the system, so that it can be restarted in its previous state when next brought to the foreground.

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo>
```

However according to android documentation this functionality was depreciated in API level 21.

> As of Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP, this method is no longer available
>   to third party applications: the introduction of document-centric
>   recents means it can leak person information to the caller. For
>   backwards compatibility, it will still return a small subset of its
>   data: at least the caller's own tasks, and possibly some other tasks
>   such as home that are known to not be sensitive.

I don't think you are able to do what you want for the reasons quoted by Android above, for more information you can head to [this link.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29)

Comment: I already knew that I can read out the running processes like that, but only the running processes and not the FROZEN ONES which are still in memory but not running.